# Icons not aligned properly in JQuery Mobile 1.3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I have just downloaded that latest version of JQuery Mobile - 1.3.2 version.

I have noticed all my icons are now out of position.

If you look at the images below, you can see they are slightly to the left / top of the buttons.

Has anyone else got this bug / know a solution?

[image]

[image]

EDIT - This picture probably shows the problem best:

[image]

Comment: This is happening in Chrome for me

Comment: What jquery version are you using? Are you overriding `ui-btn` or buttons in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't come across this issue, maybe due to **CSS Conflict**.  But I have an idea to solve this issue.

Try to **inspect the element using Developers Tools(F12)** and **override** it in your own stylesheet.

Here is a sample screenshot

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was a style sheet problem. I temporarily removed my other style sheet and it worked, problem solved! Cheers!